# OpenGL ES Run multiple shaders

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, shader

Based on a previous question I've been researching how to run multiple shaders in one pass (ie have one FBO and render to texture). This is OpenGLES 2 on Iphone.

I've created some code which runs but only for one frame. So obviously I'm doing something wrong but I just can't spot it.

The inout data is the corevideo buffer from the camera.

Any pointers or fixes are extremely welcomed :).

Thanks,

Simon

PS: I've put everything into one method for now - just so I can simply focus on getting it to work!

```
- (void) PingPong:(CVImageBufferRef)cameraframe;
{
int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraframe);

int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraframe);

// Build the first FBO - this is wasteful - don't do this everytime
GLuint firstFBO;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &firstFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, firstFBO);

// Build the first texture and copy the video stuff into it
GLuint sourcetexture;
glGenTextures(1, &sourcetexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sourcetexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


// Build the second texture
GLuint nextTexture;
glGenTextures(1, &nextTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, nextTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// Attach the texture to our first FBO
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, sourcetexture, 0);


// Using BGRA extension to pull in video frame data directly
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraframe));

//glDrawBuffer(sourcetexture);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sourcetexture);
glUseProgram(greyscaleProgram);

// Now do the 2nd pass using the sourcetexture as input
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, nextTexture, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, nextTexture);
glUseProgram(program);

// Present the framebuffer to the render buffer
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

// Clean up stuff
glDeleteTextures(1, &sourcetexture);
glDeleteTextures(1, &nextTexture);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is your draw code? Drawing is what triggers shader execution, and your code as i see it right now has zero draw calls (glDrawArrays, glDrawElements, etc), so it's not working because you're not drawing.

Draw a full screen quad to trigger shader execution for each pass and it will work.

Also it's recommended to use glCheckFramebufferStatus to check that your FBO configuration is supported and will work in your GL implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I take it I'll need to do one for each glUseProgram to trigger the render to the buffer/texture? So one to go into the texture and one to the final render buffer?

Comment: @Simon - Yes, you'll need to do a glDraw* for every time you want to render something using a shader program.  If you want an example of this in action, see [this sample application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip), where I do a two-stage rendering using shaders just like what you're attempting.

Comment: @Brad - Ahh is this where you are using read pixels to read into the fbo via rawPositionPixels and then calling setDisplay... and UseProgram?

Comment: @Simon - You don't need to use `glReadPixels()` just to pass information between the FBOs.  I do so because I hadn't yet found a good way to do whole-image color averaging on the GPU, so I read the pixels back into the application and do a CPU-bound processing routine on them.  If you don't need to access the pixel values in this way, don't use `glReadPixels()`, because it's very slow.

Comment: @Anyone :). I've been mucking about with this for days now and, though you've both been kind enough to answer, I'm still either getting black screens or one shader overwriting another. What's best here? To ask again or paste my original code as another answer and spawn another thread to this question?

Comment: @Matias - I have posted another question but with my original code before I started. A bit of a step backwards but I was running the risk of just cargo cult programming so I wanted to start again with a clean slate. Thanks for all your advise so far by the way!